# magento , sales order save after how correctly update order data

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

How correctly update status for order?

i have this code, but it's not working for me

```
public function salesOrderSaveAfter($event){

        //check for fires twice 
        if(!Mage::registry('backorder_daniilkrok_observer')){
            $order = $event->getOrder();
            $orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
            Mage::register('backorder_daniilkrok_observer',true);

            Mage::log('i here');
            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
                $oldQty = (int)$item->getProduct()->getStockItem()->getQty();
                $qtyOrdered = (int)$item->getQtyOrdered();

                $differenceQty = $oldQty - $qtyOrdered;

                //increase the price by 25%
                if($oldQty > 0 AND $differenceQty <= 0 ){
                    $product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                    $price = $product_model->getPrice();
                    $newPrice = $price + (($price * 25) / 100);
                    $product_model->setPrice($newPrice);
                    $product_model->save();

                    //update status for order
                    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
                    $state = 'new';
                    $status = 'backorder_status';
                    $isCustomerNotified = true;
                    $order->setState($state, $status, $isCustomerNotified);
                    $order->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$order->setState($state, $status, $isCustomerNotified);` looks like a problem.

To set multiple values on an object, they have to be specified separately, as in `$order->setState($state)->setStatus($status)`.

However, I think what you actually want to do is create a new `sales/order_status_history` object. This is the "Magento" way, that will ensure that all the corresponding boxes are checked.

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` includes the `addStatusHistoryComment` method, which returns a `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History` object that can be further modified by setting a value for `isCustomerNotified`.

See the `addCommentAction` method in  `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php` for an example:

```
public function addCommentAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $response = false;
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('history');
                $notify = isset($data['is_customer_notified']) ? $data['is_customer_notified'] : false;
                $visible = isset($data['is_visible_on_front']) ? $data['is_visible_on_front'] : false;

                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'], $data['status'])
                    ->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible)
                    ->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);
. . .
```